# is there any library available to execute sparql queries to triplestore in node js/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, sparql, semantic-web

I am looking for any libraries so that I can query the triplestore database using SPARQL statements and also the server has username, password so library with credential feature would be great!

Comment: and you couldn't find any by using a search engine of your choice with the terms "sparql + javascript + api"? SPARQL queries are done via HTTP protocol nayways, why not using a standard HTTP request API for JS? I'm sure then most common of those support auth mechanisms, no?

Comment: https://zazuko.github.io/sparql-http-client/#/?id=advanced-topics should work if your server uses basic auth.

Comment: @berezovskyi i see but where can i write username password?

Comment: In the constructor? https://zazuko.github.io/sparql-http-client/#/?id=creating-a-client